# Fetching profile image from Azure, using Passport token

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, passport.js

Using this: https://github.com/auth0/passport-azure-ad-oauth2

The callback:

```
const callback = async (accessToken, _: string, params, profile, done) => {
  const waadProfile: IAzureUser = jwt.decode(
    params.id_token,
    process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
  );

  const photo = getPhoto(accessToken);
...
```

I want to [fetch the profile image](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0):

```
GET graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "95e2deac-969c-4e4a-b577-e33376bb66d4",
            "date": "2019-10-17T08:33:01"
        }
    }
}
```

The token is wrong. Have tried both the `accessToken` and `params.id_token`. Not working. What token am I suppose to use?

Comment: could you verified that token has required permissions??

Comment: How do I do that? I'm requesting the signed in users photo: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value

Comment: Invalid audience indicates the token is for an API other than Graph.What resource did you use? To verify your token you can paste the token in https://jwt.ms to decode it. Look at the "aud" and "scopes" claims.

Comment: Yes I guess it's from the passport API. My code is same as in the readme.md https://github.com/auth0/passport-azure-ad-oauth2/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

You're either missing or passing the wrong `resource` value. The resource should be `https://graph.microsoft.com` or `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`.

```js
passport.use(new AzureAdOAuth2Strategy({
  clientID: '{YOUR_CLIENT_ID}',
  clientSecret: '{YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET}',
  callbackURL: '{YOUR_CALLBACK_URL}',
  resource: '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000',
  useCommonEndpoint: true
},
```